# CSS Drop-Shadow Along SVG Path not Rendering in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I have an SVG triangle that I wrote in HTML:

```css
path {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 3px 17px rgb(0 0 0 / 1));
}
```

```html
<svg style="height: 36px; width: 100%; background-color: #EAEAEA ;" viewBox="0 0 436 217" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="Tagline-triangle is-red first triangle" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="triangle-shadow-downward" d="M0 0H436V217L0 0Z"></path>
</svg>
```

which create the following effect:
[image]

where there is a subtle shadow along the diagonal of the triangle. This works perfectly fine on Chrome and Firefox, however, on Safari, the shadow does not show up at all. Does anyone know why, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac but this might work.

```css
path {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 3px 17px rgb(0 0 0 / 1));
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 3px 17px rgb(0 0 0 / 1));
  -moz-filter:  drop-shadow(5px 3px 17px rgb(0 0 0 / 1));
  -ms-filter:  drop-shadow(5px 3px 17px rgb(0 0 0 / 1));
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(5px 3px 17px rgb(0 0 0 / 1));
}
```

```html
<svg style="height: 36px; width: 100%; background-color: #EAEAEA ;" viewBox="0 0 436 217" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="Tagline-triangle is-red first triangle" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="triangle-shadow-downward" d="M0 0H436V217L0 0Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe this code had any effect.

Comment: @NicolasGimelli I just tryed your code on the safari from my ipad and it works, so it might be a problem at your side.

Comment: I’ve just tried it on an iPad with Safari and it does not work. The triangles are there but the slight shadow under the red is not there.

Comment: @ThomasVerbruggen I don't believe so. I've tried it on multiple Apple devices, including Safari from a co-worker in a different location, and neither rendered the shadows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).